# Change Keyboard suggestions bar text in swift

Tags: swift, keyboard

Is it possible to change the text of keyboard suggestions bar like in the default remainders  app on iOS?

[image: Remainders app]

I tried this but it doesn't show in the suggestions bar.

```
let firstBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "First", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(itemPressed))
let secondBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Second", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(itemPressed))
let leadingBarButtonItemGroup = UIBarButtonItemGroup(barButtonItems: [firstBarButtonItem, secondBarButtonItem], representativeItem: nil)
        
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = [leadingBarButtonItemGroup]
```